# BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using ruby-build 20210420) - erro ano instalar ruby usando asdf

Tags: ruby

Ao tentar instalar o ruby pelo asdf com o comando:

```
asdf install ruby 2.7.2
```

Obtenho o resultado:

```
Downloading ruby-2.7.2.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.2.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.7.2...

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using ruby-build 20210420)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20210428000115.45731.J08MXP
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20210428000115.45731.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for _setjmp as a macro or function... yes
checking for sigsetjmp as a macro or function... no
checking for setjmp type... __builtin_setjmp
checking for prefix of external symbols... NONE
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking if make is GNU make... ./configure: line 29863: make: command not found
no
checking for safe null command for make... configure: error: no candidate for safe null command
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Você não tem o `GNU Make` instalado, ao menos o *script* de configuração, o `configure`, parou neste ponto. Instale-o com:

```
sudo apt install make
```

E como você está compilado algo para o Ruby eu sugiro também instalar o pacote `ruby2.7-dev` que instalará aquilo que você precisa para compilar coisas para a linguagem.

Answer (score -1):

você vai precisar instalar alguns pacotes para compilar o ruby:

```bsh
sudo apt install build-essential libxml2 libssl-dev
```

esses são os principais que conheço